# Select Every Instance Of A Div Without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have several divs on the page. I need my code to cycle through the divs at regular intervals and collect all their ids, then send a request to the server to see if the value have been updated and if so change it. I already know how to do most of the code but the only part I am stuck on is writing plain old JavaScript that will loop through and select all the divs to query against the database.

I've written similar code before with `jQuery.each`, but this time I'm looking for a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: or `querySelectorAll('div')`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var allDIVs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
// allDIVs is a NodeList

for(var i = 0, len = allDIVs.length; i < len; i++ ){
    var currDIV = allDIVs[i];
    // more code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *getElementsByTagName*:

```
function getDivIds() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var ids = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=divs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (divs[i].id) {
      ids.push(divs[i].id);
    }
  }
  return ids;
}
```

or in modern browsers (not IE<9):

```
function getDivIds() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var ids = [];
  [].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
    if (div.id) ids.push(div.id);
  });
  return ids;
}
```

Since the divs collection is live, you only need to get it once, so you could do (again in modern browsers):

```
var getDivIds = (function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var each = Array.prototype.forEach;

  return function() {
    var ids = [];
    each.call(divs, function(div){if (div.id) ids.push(div.id)});
    return ids;
  }
}());
```